# CSS selectors not working as expected when using each and components in svelte

Tags: css, css-selectors, svelte

Why svelte declares unused CSS selector when there could be inner elements inside my Component?

```html
<div class="users">
    {#each [1,2,3,4,5] as id}
        <User name={id} />
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .users > * {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Error:
`Unused CSS selector ".users > *" (12:4)`

Repl:
https://svelte.dev/repl/6c8b4a6a808c4aee80e51af58b4fcda4?version=3.44.0

User is a regular div. Not sure if I should use another pattern to achieve this.

Comment: think you class 'container' should be 'users'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple things:

- I don't see a `users` class in your code, the `div` has a class `container`, I guess you meant that one
- Svelte scopes all styles to the current component, which means elements of children are not targeted. In your case, you want to target any direct child of your `div`, but the elements are inside `User`, so this doesn't work

Solution: Use `:global` which tells Svelte to not scope the selector to the current component:

```
<script>
import User from './User.svelte'
</script>

<div class="users">
    {#each [1,2,3,4,5] as id}
        <User name={id} />
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    /* you could also write :global(.users > *) but that
       would also target any "users" class somewhere else */
    .users > :global(*) {
        border: 3px solid teal;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Svelte the css is scoped to the component by default, so styles defined inside a component will have no effect anywhere else.
(the styled elements inside a component get an additional class like 'svelte-1g7lik1')

The 'users' div is except for the User component - which is not affected by the styling - empty, so the declaration has no effect on anything and hence is redundant

You can solve the problem by wrapping your css statement in :global()

See this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fa6f774a208a452f866c10bc5debe76a?version=3.44.0)

```html
<script>
import User from './User.svelte'
</script>

<div class="users">
    {#each [1,2,3,4,5] as id}
        <User name={id} />
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .users > :global(*){
      border: 3px solid teal;
    }

    /*>> .users.svelte-16kesww>* {...} in bundle.css  */
      >> affects 'childcomponent-children'

  
    :global(.users > *) {  
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 0 0 pink;
    }

    /*>> .users > * {...} in bundle.css
      >> affects globally all children of elements with class 'users' */
</style>
```